# Please help to know why single.php crashes after I add this code

Tags: php

This is my single.php. I'm using the Suffusion theme and the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

I'm trying to display custom fields based in a specific post category. The code works fine if I remove the php tags and the if statement, but the custom fields show in every post. If I add the php tags, the page crashes.

I put "MY CODE STARTS HERE" and "MY CODE ENDS HERE" markers for you to find my code. Please help if possible.

```
    <?php
    /**
     * This is the template file for single posts. It is used by single posts of any post type.
     *
     */
    get_header();
    ?>
        <div id="main-col">
            <?php suffusion_before_begin_content(); ?>
        <div id="content">
    <?php
    global $post, $suffusion_is_cpt;
    if ($post->post_type != 'post') {
        $suffusion_is_cpt = true;
        add_filter('suffusion_byline_position', 'suffusion_single_cpt_byline_position');
        add_action('suffusion_add_taxonomy_bylines_line', 'suffusion_cpt_line_taxonomies', 10, 2);
        add_action('suffusion_add_taxonomy_bylines_pullout', 'suffusion_cpt_line_taxonomies', 10, 4);
        global $suffusion_cpt_layouts, $suf_cpt_bylines_posted_by, $suf_cpt_bylines_comments, $suf_cpt_bylines_permalinks, $suf_cpt_bylines_post_date;
        if (isset($suffusion_cpt_layouts[$post->post_type]) && isset($suffusion_cpt_layouts[$post->post_type]['byline-contents'])) {
            $byline_contents = explode(',', $suffusion_cpt_layouts[$post->post_type]['byline-contents']);
            $suf_cpt_bylines_posted_by = in_array('posted-by', $byline_contents) ? 'show' : 'hide';
            $suf_cpt_bylines_comments = in_array('comments', $byline_contents) ? 'show' : 'hide';
            $suf_cpt_bylines_permalinks = in_array('permalink', $byline_contents) ? 'show' : 'hide';
            $suf_cpt_bylines_post_date = in_array('date', $byline_contents) ? 'show' : 'hide';
        }
        else {
            $suf_cpt_bylines_posted_by = false;
            $suf_cpt_bylines_comments = false;
            $suf_cpt_bylines_permalinks = false;
            $suf_cpt_bylines_post_date = false;
        }
    }

    if (have_posts()) {
        while (have_posts()) {
            the_post();
            global $suf_prev_next_above_below;
            if ($suf_prev_next_above_below == 'above' || $suf_prev_next_above_below == 'above-below') {
                get_template_part('custom/prev-next');
            }
            $original_post = $post;
            do_action('suffusion_before_post', $post->ID, 'blog', 1);
    ?>
        <article <?php post_class();?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <?php
            suffusion_after_begin_post();
        ?>
            <div class="entry-container fix">
                <div class="entry fix">
    <?php
            suffusion_content();

    ?>
                </div><!--/entry -->


    //MY CODE STARTS HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    <?php
    if (in_category('movies')){
    <span style="font-size:16px">
    <strong>Movie:</strong> <?php the_field('movie_name'); ?> (<?php the_field('movie_year'); ?>)<br/>
    <strong>IMDb:</strong> <?php the_field('imdb_link'); ?><br/>
    <strong>Rotten Tomatoes: <?php the_field('rt_link'); ?> <br/><br/>
    </span>
    <br/><br/>
    }
?>
    //MY CODE ENDS HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    <?php
            // Due to the inclusion of Ad Hoc Widgets the global variable $post might have got changed. We will reset it to the original value.
            $post = $original_post;
            suffusion_after_content();
    ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-container -->
    <?php
            suffusion_before_end_post();
            comments_template();
    ?>
        </article><!--/post -->
    <?php
            do_action('suffusion_after_post', $post->ID, 'blog', 1);
            if ($suf_prev_next_above_below == 'below' || $suf_prev_next_above_below == 'above-below') {
                get_template_part('custom/prev-next');
            }
        }
    }
    else {
    ?>
            <article class="post fix">
            <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'suffusion'); ?></p>
            </article><!--post -->

    <?php
    }
    ?>
          </div><!-- content -->
        </div><!-- main col -->
    <?php
    get_footer();
    ?>
}
```

Comment: Fix the all syntax error.

Comment: I tried that, but I can't spot them. Help? Only in my code, the rest of the file has no changes.

Comment: you try to output html without exiting php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `<?php` and `?>`

```
<?php

if( in_category( 'movies' ) ) {    // this (end php, start html) -> ?> 

    <span style="font-size:16px">
        <strong>Movie:</strong> <?php the_field( 'movie_name' ); ?> (<?php the_field( 'movie_year' ); ?>)<br/>
        <strong>IMDb:</strong> <?php the_field( 'imdb_link' ); ?><br/>
        <strong>Rotten Tomatoes: <?php the_field( 'rt_link' ); ?> <br/><br/>
    </span>
    <br/><br/> <?php // <- this (end html, start php)
} ?>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! That was the problem. As you see, I'm very novice in php.

Comment: Ok, understood. First time here.